# Access component from iframe source in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have the feeling this is something simple that I am missing, but I haven't been able to find a solution to this so far. I'm somewhat of a web noob so I apologize if this was answered somewhere already and I missed it.

Below is a sample of what I'm attempting to do. I have input (button_hide) and div (box) components in "example.php" which is the source of the iframe that I would like to access and to perform jquery functions on.

I saw somewhere that contents is the way to access it from the iframe but this doesn't seem to be working.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<iframe id="iframe" height="450" width="100%" frameBorder="0" src="example.php" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#iframe').contents().find('#box').slideUp();
  var hideButton = $('#iframe').contents().find('#button_hide');

  hideButton.click(function(){
    alert('Hi');  
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: `document` ready doesn't mean that your `iframe` content is also loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with the jquery library not importing properly. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ method instead of ready.

Comment: After reading that link, it sounds like load is definitely the right way to go for iframes, however changing document.ready to iframe.load or window.load does not fix the issue of the click of the button having no effect. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="iframe" height="450" width="100%" frameBorder="0" src="example.php" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#iframe #box').slideUp();
var hideButton = $('#iframe #button_hide')

hideButton.click(function(){
alert('Hi');  
});

});
</script>
```

this will work.

Comment: Just tried this and still no response from the click like the original code. Thanks though.